# Scala - Get value of variable through another variable of same object

Tags: scala

[image: UML class diagram]

From the UML diagram, it shows that **getGrade(String)** is a method of the class Quiz. My understanding is that the **String should be the title of the Quiz**. But how do you **get score of the Quiz based on the title** you put in as the parameter?

And the question asks us to " **Write Scala code for Quiz class with the given grading scheme for Quiz in getGrade function. For mark above 70 the grade is A.**".

Below is my code but it won't work.

```
def getGrade(title:String):String={
    if(title.score >= 70)
        val grade:String = A
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` is a keyword that is used to created a stored non-modifiable field or local variable. In your case you probably should map `score` field of type `Double` to `String` representation so this is a computed rather than stored information. What is the purpose of the additional `String` argument and of `availableScore` field in the `Assignment` class is unclear. Here is my best guess:

```
abstract class Assignment(val title: String, val score: Double, val availableScore: Double) {
  def grade(studentName: String): String
}

class Quiz(title: String, score: Double, availableScore: Double) extends Assignment(title, score, availableScore) {
  override def grade(studentName: String): String = {
    val grade = score match {
      case s if s >= 70 => "A"
      case s if s >= 50 => "B"
      // map rest ranges from score to grade
      case _ => "F"
    }

    s"$studentName's grade for quiz '$title' is $grade"
  }
}
```